# Custom module and template.tpl.php files

Tags: 7, theming

I am just getting started with custom modules for my test site on my localhost. Is there a simple demonstration online where there is an example of using a mymodule.tpl.php files to render my content?

At the moment I have create a hook_menu() function also a function for the page call, all it does is return some text.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a lot of examples of use of the Drupal API for module developers in the Drupal documentation. In particular, you may find the [Examples for Developers](http://drupal.org/project/examples) module handy, especially the "theming_example" sub-module. This is not an actually functional module, but just a container for a lot of example code that new developers can test, manipulate and learn from.

Answer (score 4):

I know its too late to answer this now, but still could be helpful to many: 
This is the best and exact to the point: http://www.nicklewis.org/drupal-hackers-cookbook/theming/hook_theme-and-template-files

Comment: This link is for Drupal 6